# Optaplanner cloning solution between afterVariableChanged and calculateScore

Tags: optaplanner

We are using OptaPlanner with the IncrementalScoreCalculator model and were working under the assumption that intermediate clones (for saving a new best solution when encontered) were made just after the calculateScore call (therefore using the newly calculated hard/soft score in order to determine whether it is the best solution).

As we are working with a problem state that is only updated in the calculateScore phase (due to performance reasons) this leads to the selection of a new solution with an out of date score.

Is there any way we can configure the best solution to be selected/cloned only just after the calculateScore step?

**Update:** Running the solver with the `FULL_ASSERT` directive avoids the issue : cloning always happens after `calculateScore()`. However, if no directive is used the following happens (each line represents a **Solution Id - Iteration** key):

2022-10-20 01:05:02.828  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1000 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.828  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1000 - CalculateScore

2022-10-20 01:05:02.829  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.829  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.829  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.829  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.829  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.829  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.830  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.830  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.830  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.830  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:02.830  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] c.o.p.o.h.s.SNPSchedulingSolutionCloner  : 4-1001 - CloneSolution **-- here is where the solution is cloned, before a new scoreCalculation and in the same thread --**

2022-10-20 01:05:03.089  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:03.089  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:03.089  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:03.089  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:03.089  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:03.089  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - AfterVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:03.089  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1001 - CalculateScore

2022-10-20 01:05:03.263  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1002 - BeforeVariableChanged

2022-10-20 01:05:03.263  INFO 86000 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] .SNPSchedulingIncrementalScoreCalculator : 4-1002 - AfterVariableChanged

We have tested with OptaPlanner 8.29.0.Final and 8.16.1.Final.

Evaluating the `BestSolutionRecaller` method this is what I've found:
[image: BestSolutionRecaller]
A clone is created as the method understands that the current score (0 hard / 7 soft, from iteration 1000) is better than the best score from SolverScope (0 hard / 0 soft). However, at a prior iteration (741) a best score of (0 hard / 7 soft) had already been found.

Comment: How have you proven that the `calculateScore()` call happens after solution cloning? Because it makes absolutely no sense - the score *has to be* calculated before any decisions are made. Consequently, have you proven that your code passes the `FULL_ASSERT` environment mode checks? My working theory is that the order of operations is correct, it is in fact a score corruption in your calculator that gives you the appearance of getting stale scores.

Comment: Hi Lukáš, I have followed your suggestion and updated the question with  a log that indicates the sequence in which each method is called. Running the code with FULL_ASSERT ensures that the cloning method runs after calculateScore(). However, when I do not set the environment mode the behavior shown above is observed.

Comment: Thank you. You may also want to try NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT, as that will deliberately remove some score calculations which FULL_ASSERT otherwise adds.

Answer (score 1):

From the sequence of operations you posted, I do not (yet) see an issue. The fact that there are multiple variable change events before a score is calculated *could* be totally normal; a move that switches two vehicle destinations does two variable updates, a pillar move that changes all beds in the same department could possibly update dozens of variables.

It is logical that score calculation would only be called after all of those updates have been triggered, as anywhere in the middle would be an inconsistent solution state. Score calculation must happen *after a move finishes*, not after events are triggered.

Furthermore, this code is exercised by our users daily, it is also heavily covered with tests. It is the very core of OptaPlanner, it *has to* work. If we had a bug in here, we would have been notified immediately, and not months after the fact. (I assume your mention of 8.16.1.Final means that you are seeing the issue there as well. That release is, by now, nearly a year old.)

All of the above leads me to conclude that there is no issue on OptaPlanner side. Running `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT` environment mode can either point you to an issue in your score calculator implementation, or prove me wrong. That said, if the assert mode passes, I'm going to have to see proof that, when the move finishes, there really is no score calculation. This would be a serious bug, and that would be the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your support Lukáš. I will develop and publish a minimal test case showing the cloning behavior - for the moment we are circumventing the issue with a routine that identifies and stores the current best solution (updated at each calculateScore() call) so that when the solver stops we have a fully consistent solution available.